# Alpha Sculpt Brush blurry

Tags: sculpting

I have no idea what is going on but when I try to sculpt with a high res alpha, the texture shows up extremely pixelated. This is on multires level 7, so mesh resolution is not the problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you think the mesh detail is not the problem? You could enable wireframe view and zoom in to your mesh, I think you will discover that the mesh density is still not enough to support that level of brush detail you are expecting.

Comment: I'm with @GeraldDegeneve here. 100k faces is not high enough for the level of detail you expect.